# Proving Binomial Identity using PIE

Tags: combinatorics

Let $m\geq n\geq 1$. Prove the following identity using PIE:  $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\left(\begin{array}{c} m-k \\ n \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c} n \\ k \end{array}\right)=1$.

For $i=1,2,\dots,n$, let $A_i$ be the set of all $(m-n)$-subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,m\}$ that contain $i$. Use this to count the number of $(m-n)$-subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,m\}$ that do not contain any elements of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$.

This is what I have so far:

Let $A_i=\{(m-n)\subseteq \{1,2,\dots,m\}\ \text{containing }i,\ \text{for }i=1,2,\dots n\}$. For each $A_i$, there are $\left(\begin{array}{c} n \\ 1 \end{array}\right)$ ways of choosing them multiplied $\left(\begin{array}{c} m-1 \\ m-n-1 \end{array}\right)$ elements. Then for each intersection of two $A_i$'s, there are $\left(\begin{array}{c} n \\ 2 \end{array}\right)$ ways of choosing them multipied by $\left(\begin{array}{c} m-2 \\ m-n-2 \end{array}\right)$ elements. Thus for $k$ many intersections of the $A_i$'s, there are $\left(\begin{array}{c} n \\ k \end{array}\right)$ choices multiplied by $\left(\begin{array}{c} m-k \\ m-n-k \end{array}\right)$ elements. Thus \begin{align*}
    |A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_n|&=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}\left(\begin{array}{c} m-k \\ m-n-k \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c} n \\ k \end{array}\right)\\
    &=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}\left(\begin{array}{c} m-k \\ n \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c} n \\ k \end{array}\right)
\end{align*}

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

define for $i\in${$1,...,n$} $A_i$ to be the set of all subsets of ${1,...,m}$ such that $|A_i|=n$ and $i\notin A_i$ (means all n-subsets of [m] that do not contain i).

Now by PIE we know that $|\bigcap_{k=1}^{n}A_k ^C| =|S|+ \sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^k\sum_{I\subseteq [m], |I|=k} |\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i|= \sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\sum_{I\subseteq [m], |I|=k} |\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i| $ (where S is the set of all n-subsets of [m])

now we see that $\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\sum_{I\subseteq [m], |I|=k} |\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i|  = \sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k $$ n\choose k  $$m-k \choose n$ because for every $I\subseteq[m] $with $|I|=k : |\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i|=$$m-k\choose n$ and there are $n \choose k$ ways to choose such I.

also $\bigcap_{k=1}^{n}A_k ^C =${{$1,2,...,n  $}} (singleton containing only [n]) therefor we get:
$1 = |\bigcap_{k=1}^{n}A_k ^C| = \sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k $$ n\choose k  $$m-k \choose n$